# How do I format a duration into hours, minutes, and seconds?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, time, formatting, string-formatting

I want to convert duration into milliseconds.  So I have this expression …

```
Time.parse(duration_expr).seconds_since_midnight * 1000
```

in which the duration expression is of the form “HH:MM:SS”.  However, if the duration expression is of the form “MM:SS” or just “SS”, the above fails to yield the correct number of milliseconds.  How do I take an expression like “MM:SS” or “SS” and convert it into “HH:MM:SS”?

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
def convert_to_hrs(string)
  case string.count(':')
  when 0
    '00:00:' + string.rjust(2, '0')
  when 1
    '00:' + string
  else
    string
  end
end
[30] pry(main)> convert_to_hrs('1')
=> "00:00:01"
[31] pry(main)> convert_to_hrs('12:01')
=> "00:12:01"
[32] pry(main)> convert_to_hrs('12:12:01')
=> "12:12:01"
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just pad the string? i.e. if it's 5 characters long, put "00:" at the front, and if it's 2 characters long, put "00:00:" at the front. `Time.parse` will work on both of those just fine.

I'm sure there are prettier ways to use regular expressions and string formatters, but that's the basic logic you want. (As long as your formats aren't going to get more complicated than implied here.)